# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'Myurl' No action was found on the controller 'controllername' that matches the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Webapimethod Work well  in RestConsole but when that Webapi method is called in AndroidApplication it shows Error

{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://beatrootstudios.co.in/api/apiCityInfo/PostSearchByCategory'.",

"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'apiCityInfo' that matches the request."
}

Even I tried My chaging Controller Name From CityInfo To apiCityInfo and also By
Various Routing Tricks as mentions in many examples  in google

I also tried by putting Actionname with httppost verb as mentioned in controller below ...

My Contoller Code Is

```
public class apiCityInfoController : ApiController
{
    private DBContext db = new DBContext();
     [HttpPost, ActionName("PostSearchByCategory")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostSearchByCategory(string CategoryName)
    {
        var errorMessage = "";
        int errorCode = 0;
        //string json = null;
        string jsonResult = "Error";
        var SubCategory = db.CityDatas.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Equals(CategoryName)).ToList().FirstOrDefault().SubCategoryName; 

        try
        {

            if (SubCategory !=null)
            {
                //errorMessage = " Login ID cannot be Null ";
                //errorCode = 1;
                var SubCategoryresult = (from p in db.CityDatas
                              where p.CategoryName.Equals(CategoryName)
                              select new
                              {

                                  SubCategoryName = p.SubCategoryName,


                              }
                   ).ToList();
                var data = new
                {
                    Result = new
                    {
                        //ErrorCode = errorCode,
                        //ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
                        ResultSet = SubCategoryresult,

                    }
                };
                return Json(data);

            }
            else
            {
                var Dataresult = (from p in db.CityDatas
                                         where p.CategoryName.Equals(CategoryName)
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             DataImage = p.DataImage,
                                             DataName = p.DataName,
                                             DataAddress = p.DataAddress,
                                             DataPhoneNo = p.DataPhoneNo,                                                
                                         }
                 ).ToList();
                    var data = new
                    {
                        Result = new
                        {
                            ResultSet = Dataresult,


                        }
                    };

                    //jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                    return Json(data);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorCode = 401;
            errorMessage = e.Message;
            var data = new
            {
                Result = new
                {
                    ErrorCode = errorCode,
                    ErrorMessage = "CategoryName Not Exists",

                }
            };

            jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        }

        return Ok(jsonResult);
    }
```

Model Part Is

```
[Table("CityInfo")] 
public class CityData
{
    //[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    [Key]
    public int CityInfo_Id { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public String DataImage { get; set; }
    public String DataName { get; set; }
    public String DataAddress { get; set; }
    public String DataPhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext in Model

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{

    public DBContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<WebApi.Models.CityData> CityDatas { get; set; }

}
```

Table Definition Is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CityInfo] (
[CityInfo_Id]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CategoryName]    NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[SubCategoryName] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[DataImage]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[DataName]        NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[DataAddress]     NVARCHAR (300) NULL,
[DataPhoneNo]     NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CityInfo_Id] ASC)
```

);

WebApi Config.cs file Is

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //name: "DefaultApi",
            //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
             name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Post", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Route Config.cs file Is

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Global.asx File is

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(null);

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `CategoryName`is non-optional, so you need to include it as a parameter in your request. The URL should look like this: `http://beatrootstudios.co.in/api/apiCityInfo/PostSearchByCategory?CategoryName=category` and you probably want to make this a GET action, as opposed to a POST.

Comment: Thanks  Get method is working well with no issue but problem arises when i use Httppost Method so could u  Plz help me out for issue in httppost method bcoz for security reasons to use get method wiil not be gud practice...